# Drop down list does not work

Tags: javascript, html

im learning programming and i have got hands on my first website. My drop down list only allows engineering. Please help me out. Because i can not understand why it does not work. Thanks in advance.

Here is my java script code that i have tried.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    var farming = {
        program: "Agriculture",
        course: "Farming",
        tuition: 800000
    };

    var consumption = {
        program: "Agriculture",
        course: "Animal consumption",
        tuition: 800000
    };

    var livestock = {
        program: "Agriculture",
        course: "Livestock",
        tuition: 800000
    };

    var crop = {
        program: "Agriculture",
        course: "Crop growing",
        tuition: 800000
    };

    var coding = {
        program: "Ict",
        course: "Computer coding",
        tuition: 1000000
    };

    var science = {
        program: "Ict",
        course: "Computer science",
        tuition: 1000000
    };

    var systems = {
        program: "Ict",
        course: "Information systems",
        tuition: 1000000
    };

    var programming = {
        program: "Ict",
        course: "Computer programming",
        tuition: 1000000
    };

    var mechanical = {
        program: "Engineering",
        course: "Mechanical Engineering",
        tuition: 1200000
    };

    var electrical = {
        program: "Engineering",
        course: "Electrical Engineering",
        tuition: 1200000
    };
    var telecom = {
        program: "Engineering",
        course: "Telecom Engineering",
        tuition: 1200000
    };
    var civil = {
        program: "Engineering",
        course: "Civil Engineering",
        tuition: 1200000
    };

    var courses = [mechanical , electrical , telecom, civil , consumption , livestock , farming , crop , coding , programming , science , systems]

    //var courses = ["animal consumption" , "livestock" , "farming" , "crop growing"];

    $('#program_selector').change(function() {

        if ($('#program_selector').val("2")){
            //clear all options
            $("#course_selector").find('option').remove().end()
            $("#course_selector").empty();
            //then load engineering courses
            //var selectedCourses = [];
            for (var i = 0; courses[i]; i++){
                if (courses[i].program == "Engineering") {
                    $("#course_selector").append('<option>' + courses[i].course + '</option>');

                }
            }
        }

        else if ($('#program_selector').val("4")){
            //clear all options
            $("#course_selector").find('option').remove().end();
            $("#course_selector").empty();
            //then load the agriculture courses
            for (var i = 0; courses[i]; i++){
                if (courses[i].program == "Agriculture") {
                    $("#course_selector").append('<option>' + courses[i].course + '</option>');

                }
            }
        }
        else if ($('#program_selector').val("3")){
            //clear all options
            $("#course_selector").find('option').remove().end();
            $("#course_selector").empty();
            //then load ICT courses
            //var selectedCourses = [];
            for (var i = 0; courses[i]; i++){
                if (courses[i].program == "Ict") {
                    $("#course_selector").append('<option>' + courses[i].course + '</option>');

                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant html too please?

Comment: "does not work" is not a very useful problem statement. What are you trying to accomplish, and what steps have you taken to solve this on your own? If you haven't done so already, please take some time to review the Help Center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing, you are assigning values to it:

```
  if ($('#program_selector').val("2")){
```

Try this instead:

```
$('#program_selector').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if("2" === val) {
     //
  } else if("4" === val) {
     //
  } else {
    //
  }
});
```

Comment: Arvind thanks alot i tried your answer and it works..Thanks alot

Comment: @MartinKiwala, I am glad it worked for you.

Comment: Arvind i wana thank you again man it really works with no error....Thanks alot keep in touch....

Answer (score 0):

You will be much better off using key/values to access

```
var courses = {
  "Agriculture" : {
    livestock: {
    }
  },
  "ICT" : {
    "computer programming" : {
    }
  }
}
```

now you can access as

```
courses[program][type]
```

Alternatively use an array:

```
var courses = [
  { "Please select":""},
  { livestock : ...},
  { ...... : ..... }
]
```

then the courses[sel.selectedIndex] matches the course

Comment: u r ryt man its better off that way